# Audio not playing in background when app exits on iOS with Appcelerator

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm having an issue with audio not playing in background mode when a user exits my app on a device. It works fine on the Simulator.

It is essential I get this working.

So I set up my tiapp.xml correctly (I think) with the following:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<string>audio</string>
```

I created a global audio player in app.js like this:

```
Ti.App.audioPlayer = Ti.Media.createAudioPlayer({
   allowBackground: true
});

Ti.Media.audioSessionCategory = Ti.Media.AUDIO_SESSION_CATEGORY_PLAYBACK;
```

I put the **allowBackground** option in as we are looking to push this out for Android afterwards.

Is there any other reason why this wouldn't work? It is driving me nuts!

I suspect it might be a schoolboy error due to the global audio player I set up, but I'm not sure what I've done wrong!

I'm using SDK 5.2.2.GA

Thanks

Simon

Comment: Maybe try to set `Ti.Media.audioSessionCategory` before creating the audio player?

Comment: Unfortunately, makes no difference whatsoever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent ages on this too. I had to do 2 things.

1. Add the following to the controller where I was playing the sound:

   `if (OS_IOS) { 
       Ti.Media.audioSessionCategory = Ti.Media.AUDIO_SESSION_CATEGORY_PLAYBACK; 
   }`
2. Add the following to tiapp.xml:

   `<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
   <array>
       <string>audio</string>
   </array>`

(Note, I had to put the the `UIBackgroundModes` value in an array to get it to work.)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

`Titanium.App.addEventListener('pause', function(e) {
    Titanium.Media.audioSessionCategory = Titanium.Media.MUSIC_PLAYER_STATE_PLAYING;
});`

Comment: I've had to change the audioPlayer to a videoPlayer instead to allow for scrubbing of the audio. Can this still be used this way?